# What's FirstOrDefault for DateTime in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a query that returns a `DateTime`, what's the value of `FirstOrDefault()`? Is there a generic way to get the *default* value of a C# scalar? Example:

```
var list = (from item in db.Items 
    where item.ID==1234
    select item.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit:** Assume that the column `StartDate` can't be null.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The generic way to get a default value for a given generic type is:

```
default(T)
```

where `T` is the generic type parameter in question. For reference types, this will yield `null`. For value types, this will yield a zero'd instance of the value. For `DateTime`s, this will be equivalent to `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can always "force" a different default using: `collection.DefaultIfEmpty(new DateTime(...)).First();`

Comment: How do I make it return null. Like my Entity Framework Linq to entities does?

Comment: If you want null instead of the default value for datetime, you can cast to nullable, for which the default is null:  .Select(x => (DateTime?)x)

Answer (score 7):

DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 3):

`default(DateTime)` is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

In your code, the major portion of your query is an IEnumerable of start dates from your database. Your call to FirstOrDefault() is either returning the first element of the enumerable or the default value of its type if there are no elements in the enumerable.

If the type of StartDate is indeed a date and there are no elements in the enumerable, then the result will be the datetime value I provided above.

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing its `default(DateTime)` which im guessing (again) is `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 1):

It is midnight, at the beginning 1-1-0001 .